# Query regarding In-Target Probe eXtended Debug Port (ITP-XDP)

Tags: x86, intel, terminology

Does the Intel "In-Target Probe eXtended Debug Port (ITP-XDP)" refer to the debug port on the processor, or a specialised unit of hardware that is connected to a PC via USB?

I apologise if this is a dumb question, but Intel likes to provide as little information about this as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Intel ITP-XDP can be used to debug processors or chipset related problems and on the mainboard, hardware designers need to mount XDP header near the CPU or the chipset(PCH). And yes, the XDP debugger is a very special unit, and is connected to a PC via USB and you also need to purchase Intel PDT(Platform Debug Toolkit) software, it is very expensive.